# Analyzing stability of URDF

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I just wanted to know if there is any way other than trial and error to test a robot's stability by simulation. I am developing an URDF file of a robot in which the center of mass is a little bit too high therefore sudden changes in acceleration makes it fall to one side or the other.

Is there any way in gazebo or outside of it to test the worst case scenario of a URDF file? At least to locate at all times the absolute center of mass of the robot?

I know it is a sort of vague question but I hope someone holds the answer!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211832/analyzing-stability-of-urdf/) by [maztentropy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22392/maztentropy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any existing pkgs, but [kdl_parser](http://wiki.ros.org/kdl_parser) can load URDFs, and [KDL](http://wiki.ros.org/kdl) itself contains a wealth of analysis and other algorithms that should allow you to do what you want (but it will require some work).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maztentropy](https://answers.ros.org/users/22392/maztentropy/) on 2015-06-22**:
I will definitely look into it, thanks for the hint!